# Invoke a command on a node in Karaf Cellar based on NodeID

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, karaf

At the moment, I have a cellar setup with just two nodes (meant for testing); as seen in the dump below:

```
  | Id                | Alias          | Host Name    | Port 
--+-------------------+----------------+--------------+----- 
x | 192.168.99.1:5702 | localhost:8182 | 192.168.99.1 | 5702 
  | 192.168.99.1:5701 | localhost:8181 | 192.168.99.1 | 5701
```

**Edit 1 -- Additional Information about the setup (begin):**

I have multiple cellar nodes. I am trying to make one node as a master, which is supposed to expose a management web panel via which I would like to fetch stats from all the other nodes. For this purpose, I have exposed my custom implementations of Mbeans involving my business logics. I understand that these mbeans can be invoked using Jolokia, and I am already doing that. So, that means, all these different nodes will have Jolokia installed, while the master node will have Hawtio installed (such that I can connect to slave nodes via Jolokia API through hawtio panel).

Right now, I am manually assigning the alias for every node (which refers to the web endpoint that it exposes via pax.web configuration). This is just a workaround to simplify my testing procedures.

Desired Process:

I have access to the ClusterManager service via service registry. Thus, I am able to invoke `clusterManager.listNodes()` and loop through the result in my MBean. While looping through this, all I get is the basic node info. But, if it is possible, I would like to parse the `etc/org.ops4j.pax.web.cfg` file from every node and get the port number (or the value of the property `org.osgi.service.http.port`).

While retrieving the list of nodes, I would like to get a response as:

```
{
    "Node 1": {
        "hostname": "192.168.0.100",
        "port": 5701,
        "webPort": "8181",
        "alias": "Data-Node-A"
        "id": "192.168.0.100:5701"
    },
    "Node 2": {
        "hostname": "192.168.0.100",
        "port": 5702,
        "webPort": "8182",
        "alias": "Data-Node-B",
        "id": "192.168.0.100:5702"
    }
}
```

**Edit 1 (end):**

I am trying to find a way to execute specific commands on a particular node. For example, I want to execute a command on Node *:5702 from *:5701 such that *:5702 returns the properties and values of a local configuration file.

My current method is not optimal, as I am setting the alias(the web endpoint for jolokia) of a node manually, and based on that I am retrieving my desired info via my custom mbean. I guess, this is not the best practice.

So far, I have:

`Set<Node> nodes = clusterManager.listNodes();`

thus, if I loop through this set of nodes, I would like to retrieve config settings from local configuration file from every node based on the node ID.

Do I need to implement something specific to dosgi here?

Or would it be something similar to the sample code of ping-pong (https://github.com/apache/karaf-cellar/tree/master/utils/src/main/java/org/apache/karaf/cellar/utils/ping) from apache-cellar project?

Any input on this would be very helpful.

P.S. I tried posting this in Karaf mailing list, but my posts are getting bounced.

Regards, 
Cooshal.

Comment: Although there is no generic wrapper-command, you can use `cluster:config-list --local <group> <config-pid>` to get configuration from nodes within that group. Or do you need to execute application-level business logic based on configuration values per node? The main task of Cellar is to provide synchronization of configuration within a cluster group, so the original idea behind your task would be interesting.

Comment: Hi @Ancoron ! I have updated the use case and have tried to make my use-case a bit clearer. Would I be able to achieve something like this?

Comment: I think you have to dig deeper into the existing Cellar code to figure out something. It looks like the internal Hazelcast maps are key to getting information as you already have the `ClusterManager` (have a look at some of the Config* commands code of Cellar).

Comment: yes, indeed ! currently, I am digging deeper into it. Finally, I was able to post it on the mailing list as well. So, lets see. Thank you for your suggestions and opinions. Will post back, if there is any progress.

Comment: Hi @Ancoron, I managed to create a custom command that fetches (or do whatever we instruct it to do in the node) the config information from the target node (based on NodeID). Thankfully, the ping example helped me out after I dug more into cellar. I will post the sample source code on github and share it here.

Comment: Very cool! I'd love to see a working example. :-)

Comment: here is a basic demo of how I worked around with this issue. The bundle has to be installed on all cellar nodes, and it will find its way to communicate :D
https://github.com/cooshal/Karaf-Cellar-Custom-Commmand

Comment: OK, thank you very much, so the key actually just was to get a reference to the selected `Node` via the `ClusterManager` and then just selecting the result for that node, right? But the command itself is still executed on all nodes as I see it, no?

Comment: It doesn't get executed on all the nodes. For instance, http://localhost:8181/management/modules.html?id=EAI-test-SUC&node=localhost:8184 sets the destination node. The destination could be either NodeID or Node Alias. and https://github.com/cooshal/Karaf-Cellar-Custom-Commmand/blob/master/src/main/java/infrastructure/NodeInfoCommandHandler.java will be executed on the specified destination node.

Comment: I see, you're using the Cellar `Event.destination` scope limitation. That's a neat trick! Very nice to know, indeed.

Comment: oops, my bad ! I just realized that I had pasted a local url, and I can't see a way to edit that ;)
I meant to reference this url: https://github.com/cooshal/Karaf-Cellar-Custom-Commmand/blob/master/src/main/java/mbean/infrastructure/EAINodeInfoMBean.java#L38 yeah, somehow it worked. Thanks to the sample ping utility code in the cellar repository.